# Continue a PHP While loop Breaks it instead

Tags: php, csv

A while loop is used to read every row of a CSV file except the first row. However none of the rows are read when the `if` statement is used to ignore the first row. Removing the `if` statement allows it to read all the rows as expected. Why is this?

```
$rowNumber = 1;

// Load CSV into array
$inputFileName = '/var/www/site/data.csv';
$file = fopen($inputFileName, 'r');

while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    // Ignore row #1 (headers)
    if($rowNumber == 1)
        continue;

    doSomeWork();

    // Increment row number
    $rowNumber++;
}
fclose($file);

echo 'Loaded: ' . $rowNumber . ' rows';
```

Comment: Why did you add all those tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `continue` there. Try

```
$rowNumber = 1;

// Load CSV into array
$inputFileName = '/var/www/site/data.csv';
$file = fopen($inputFileName, 'r');

while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    // Ignore row #1 (headers)
    if($rowNumber != 1)
    {
    doSomeWork();
    }

    // Increment row number
    $rowNumber++;
}
fclose($file);

echo 'Loaded: ' . $rowNumber . ' rows';
```

**Edit**

Just to explain why your `continue` didn't work as you expect. PHP Manual says

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

That means when your continue is called then your statement `$rowNumber++;` is also skipped, which means your `$rowNumber` always remains 1 and hence all the rows are skipped :)

Comment: +2^n for clearing it up at the bottom of answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you hit `continue` before the line where you increment `$rowNumber`. As a result, `$rowNumber` is still 1 on the next iteration, and it skips forward again. Try starting with $rowNumber = 0 and putting the increment at the beginning of the loop instead of the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$rowNumber = 1;

// Load CSV into array
$inputFileName = '/var/www/site/data.csv';
$file = fopen($inputFileName, 'r');

while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    // Ignore row #1 (headers)
    if($rowNumber > 1) {           
       doSomeWork();
    }
    // Increment row number
    $rowNumber++;
}
fclose($file);

echo 'Loaded: ' . $rowNumber . ' rows';
```

If the `$rowNumber` is greater that 1 then will `doSomething()`, otherwise it will just increments the `$rowNumber`

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you continue, you do not increment the $rowNumber. It is always 1. And when your file ends, then while loop breaks and file is closed.